# Program/command has been run most times

Tags: command-line

Please I need a help with command that print out what program/command has been run the most times since the system was last rebooted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command `sa` - which summarize accounting information.  You may have to first install the `acct`-package though...  You'll also get the `ac` command, which lets you see how much time individual users - or yourself - have spent logged-in, optionally split into dates.  You'll probably need to be root to use the command and access this information though...

From my system:

```
susan ~ # sa
    6603    6525.48re      20.57cp         0avio     16466k
      68      95.53re      12.12cp         0avio     61113k   ***other*
      26      36.41re       3.76cp         0avio    385039k   chromium-browse*
       8      58.44re       0.91cp         0avio     20392k   youtube-dl
       6      52.82re       0.59cp         0avio    426752k   Compositor*
      30       1.11re       0.53cp         0avio    287232k   sbcl
       8       9.57re       0.37cp         0avio    420640k   Chrome_ChildIOT*
      50       0.69re       0.30cp         0avio    117868k   avconv
      42       4.20re       0.27cp         0avio     41360k   chef-client*
       3       0.55re       0.23cp         0avio      6162k   otags
       5      14.36re       0.18cp         0avio    411878k   WorkerPool/11*
      18       0.61re       0.16cp         0avio    178645k   chromium-browse
(...)
```

"re" is the elapsed time in minutes.

(Seems like I browse the web and download videos from YouTube *way* too much...)

And the `ac` command (which also can show total per user):

```
susan ~ # ac -d
Dec  2  total       22.52
Dec  3  total       77.76
Dec  4  total       48.39
(...)
Dec 25  total       30.66
Dec 27  total        5.77
Today   total       53.96
```

(Must have accidentally used Windows on December 1st...)